# Crear objeto TreeSet a partir de uno HashSet

Tags: java

El código:

```
    public class FooFoo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Set set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add("hola");
        set.add(2.3);
        set.add(4.2F);
        set.add(1);

        TreeSet set2 = new TreeSet<>(set);
    }
}
```

El error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer   at
>   java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:52)  at
>   java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:568)   at
>   java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)   at
>   java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)  at
>   java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)    at
>   java.util.TreeSet.(TreeSet.java:160)    at
>   foo.FooFoo.main(FooFoo.java:19)

Por qué falla, no lo comprendo.

Gracias de antemano

Un cordial saludo

Answer (score 1):

Un `TreeSet` a diferencia de un `HashSet`, matiene ordenados sus elementos.
Para poder mantener los elementos ordenados tiene que poder compararlos.

Los elementos que estás queriendo agregarle son de diferente tipos, y por eso no los está pudiendo comparar.

Por ejemplo como podriamos decir que `"hola"` es mayor, menor o igual a `2.3`?

Talvez tengas una lógica armada para establecer como deben compararse los diferentes elementos.

Aunque nunca lo probé con elementos de diferentes tipos (yo no mezclo tipos en las colecciones), cuando creas el `TreeSet`, le podés pasar un objecto `Comparator` que te pemite programar como se deberían comparar los elementos entre si.

Imagino que de ser posible, tendrías que usar `typeof` primero que nada para saber de que tipo se trata y luego aplicar la lógica correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema en realidad es que estas definiendo diferentes tipos dentro del `HashSet`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Si los valores fueran del mismo tipo por ejemplo `String` podrías realizar la conversión de `HashSet` a `TreeSet` copiando todos los elementos:

```
Set set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("hola");
set.add("2.3");
set.add("4.2F");
set.add("1");

//*Convierte a TreeSet
TreeSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>(set);
```